# How to draw a line on a Google Spreadsheets Chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, graph, charts, visualization

I have an otherwise standard bar chart created from some data in a Google Sheet, the x-axis is dates, the y-axis is numbers of interactions, that is embedded in the Google Sheet.

I want to add a vertical line to the chart to indicate the date when a specific event happened that should have an impact on the data. Something to delineate the before and after of that date.

Is there any way, using the normal interface or with the Google Apps Scripts available to the Google Sheet - or something else - to draw a vertical line in an arbitrary position on the chart, possibly with a label.

The chart is then imported into a Google Slides presentation.

Answer (score 2):

use a line annotation on the x-axis.

add an annotation column to the data table after the x-axis column...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn({label: 'Date', type: 'date'});
data.addColumn({role: 'annotation', type: 'string'});  // <-- annotation column
data.addColumn({label: 'Interactions', type: 'number'});
```

set the annotation style to `'line'` in the chart config options...

```
var options = {
  annotations: {  // <-- annotation line option
    stem: {
      color: 'magenta'
    },
    style: 'line'
  },
  ...
```

then for the date on which the vertical line should display,
add the text that should be appear to the annotation column...

```
// add row
data.addRow([
  new Date(2020, 3, 21),
  'Happy Birthday!',      // <-- annotation column
  250
]);
```

use `null` for the annotation column when the vertical line should not be displayed...

```
// add row
data.addRow([
  new Date(2020, 3, 20),
  null,                   // <-- annotation column
  251
]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn({label: 'Date', type: 'date'});
  data.addColumn({role: 'annotation', type: 'string'});  // <-- annotation column
  data.addColumn({label: 'Interactions', type: 'number'});

  var eventDate = new Date(2020, 3, 21);
  var startDate = new Date(2020, 0, 1);
  var endDate = new Date();
  while (startDate.getTime() <= endDate.getTime()) {
    // determine if event occurred
    var indicateEvent = null;
    if (startDate.getTime() === eventDate.getTime()) {
      indicateEvent = 'Happy Birthday!';
    }

    // add row
    data.addRow([
      startDate,
      indicateEvent,
      (2 * ((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + 8)
    ]);

    // set next date
    startDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate() + 1);
  }

  var options = {
    annotations: {  // <-- annotation line option
      stem: {
        color: 'magenta'
      },
      style: 'line'
    },
    chartArea: {
      left: 64,
      top: 48,
      right: 32,
      bottom: 64,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    colors: ['cyan'],
    height: '100%',
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    width: '100%'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#chart {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to use within the spreadsheet though? There is no web page involved, it's just imported into a google slides presentation, not published anywhere.

Comment: you may be able to add the annotation column using a [DataViewDefinitionBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-view-definition-builder#setcolumnscolumns) in apps script with the [setColumns](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-view-definition-builder#setcolumnscolumns) method...